# CSS3 media query issue

Tags: css, media-queries

A rule I thought I had set up for only screens between `500px` and `1024px` is being applied even on screen sizes over `1024px`.

Here is the CSS. The `.red` style is correctly applied on screens less than `480px`. It's just the yellow is applied on all screens even those over the `max-width` of `1024px`.

```css
.buy {
    border: 1px solid #ABABAB;
    color: #333333;
    display: block;
    font-family: calibri,helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 25px;
    line-height: 25px;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 70px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .buy {
        color: red;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) and (min-width: 500px) {
    .buy {
        color: yellow;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you forgot `only`

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 500px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
   .buy {
     color: yellow;
   }
}
```